# Looping grade average functions with python

Tags: python, loops

So I've tried looking at similar questions and in my book but not quite connecting the dots. I have the calculations down, but I'm not understanding how/where to put a loop function to re-enter a new student with their grades (there are 12 students btw).

I tried adding a while loop in different locations marked with: <!!!>. But I always got a different error.

```
def loop():
    while newStudent =="y":
        newStudent=input("Another student? (Enter y for yes): ")
```

```
name = input("Please enter name of student: ")

!!!

def scoreInput():
\
\
def calc_average(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8):
\
\
def determine_grade(grade):
\
\
def results (score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8):
\
\

!!!

def main():
    score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8 = scoreInput()
    results (score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8)
    !!!

main()
```

Any advice on where I'm going wrong with this would be appreciated or maybe I'm just not understanding. Also a small explanation on this would be helpful to understand it. :D

Comment: If you have tried something and getting an error, posting that and solving it would be way easier than this. Can you make those changes?

Comment: According to me, all the function calls that you want to repeat should be under the while loop. So, if you call the function `loop` inside the main, all other functions and instructions should be inside the `loop` function under the while loop.

Comment: Apologies, I did try more options than I mentioned and just lost track of the errors attached to which location.

Comment: So you're saying,
def loop():
     while newStudents="y":  
\\\ All the functions \\\
newStudent=input("Another student? (Enter y for yes): ")
def main():
   loop()  ????

Comment: Yes, @Snake780. You understand correctly.

Comment: Or should I be using a for loop?

Comment: You need to be able to answer two questions first, in plain English: 1) what should happen each time through the loop? 2) what is the rule the tells you when to stop looping?

Comment: Also: do you understand what a `list` is? Can you think of a way that it might help you to store the grades for the students and to pass the information around your program?

Comment: So I answer myself, 1) a name entry, 8 different grades inputs, print of inputs with grades and a cumulative. 2) rule would be an input asking if there is another student to grade

Comment: I sort of understand `lists` but I'll definitely need to review that section again. Based on what I've seen from other questions a list would work here but I'm not catching onto it formatting wise.

Answer (score 0):

Rough pseudocode to solve your problem would be

In the code entry (main) start the loop,

```
def main():
    loop()
```

In the `loop` function have a recursion

```
def loop():
    name = input("....")

    scores = score_input()
    show_results(scores)

    new_student = input("Another student? (Enter y for yes): ")
    if new_student == 'y':
        loop()
    else:
        print('Exiting')
```

Comment: Sorry I'm late to respond. So with this are you saying that I take away the other functions and just make one loop function with everything inside?

Comment: No. just the function calls inside the loop function.

Answer (score 0):

So... the joys of coding come down to different days of testing this out. But it was simple as adding

```
for i in range(12):
```

At the very top of it all to make it run 12 times. Thanks everyone for your assistance!